# How do I reference a label in one latex file from another?

Tags: reference, latex, tufte

I have two files, a.tex and b.tex. In a.tex I have a label, \label{stuff}. In b.tex I need to refer to this label, \ref{stuff}.

I also have a main.tex file. Regardless of if I use \include{a}\include{b} or use \input{a}\input{b} the reference is not included in the pdf generated from main.tex.

The document type of main.tex is tufte-book.

Ideas?
main.tex

````
% Tufte-Style Book (Documentation Template)
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (5/1/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% The Tufte-LaTeX Developers (tufte-latex.googlecode.com)
%
% License:
% Apache License (Version 2.0)
%
% IMPORTANT NOTE:
% In addition to running BibTeX to compile the reference list from the .bib
% file, you will need to run MakeIndex to compile the index at the end of the
% document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{tufte-book} % Use the tufte-book class which in turn uses the tufte-common class

\hypersetup{colorlinks} % Comment this line if you don't wish to have colored links

\usepackage{microtype} % Improves character and word spacing

\usepackage{lipsum} % Inserts dummy text

\usepackage{booktabs} % Better horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Needed to insert images into the document
\graphicspath{{graphics/}} % Sets the default location of pictures
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio} % Improves figure scaling

\usepackage{fancyvrb} % Allows customization of verbatim environments
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize} % The font size of all verbatim text can be changed here

\newcommand\when{\  when\ }
\newcommand\otherwise{\  otherwise\ }

\newcommand\doubleplus{+\kern-1.3ex+\kern0.8ex}
\newcommand\mdoubleplus{\ensuremath{\mathbin{+\mkern-10mu+}}}

\newcommand{\false}{f\kern-0.25ex{alse}}
\newcommand\mfalse{\ensuremath{\mathbin{f\mkern-5mu alse}}}

\newcommand\f{\textit{f}}

\newcommand{\hangp}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{(}#1\makebox[0pt][l]{)}} % New command to create parentheses around text in tables which take up no horizontal space - this improves column spacing
\newcommand{\hangstar}{\makebox[0pt][l]{*}} % New command to create asterisks in tables which take up no horizontal space - this improves column spacing

\usepackage{xspace} % Used for printing a trailing space better than using a tilde (~) using the \xspace command

\newcommand{\monthyear}{\ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi\space\number\year} % A command to print the current month and year

\newcommand{\openepigraph}[2]{ % This block sets up a command for printing an epigraph with 2 arguments - the quote and the author
\begin{fullwidth}
\sffamily\large
\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\allcaps{#1}\\ % The quote
\noindent\allcaps{#2} % The author
\end{doublespace}
\end{fullwidth}
}

\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage} % Command to insert a blank page

\usepackage{units} % Used for printing standard units

\newcommand{\hlred}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}} % Print text in maroon
\newcommand{\hangleft}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{#1}} % Used for printing commands in the index, moves the slash left so the command name aligns with the rest of the text in the index 
\newcommand{\hairsp}{\hspace{1pt}} % Command to print a very short space
\newcommand{\ie}{\textit{i.\hairsp{}e.}\xspace} % Command to print i.e.
\newcommand{\eg}{\textit{e.\hairsp{}g.}\xspace} % Command to print e.g.
\newcommand{\na}{\quad--} % Used in tables for N/A cells
\newcommand{\measure}[3]{#1/#2$\times$\unit[#3]{pc}} % Typesets the font size, leading, and measure in the form of: 10/12x26 pc.
\newcommand{\tuftebs}{\symbol{'134}} % Command to print a backslash in tt type in OT1/T1

\providecommand{\XeLaTeX}{X\lower.5ex\hbox{\kern-0.15em\reflectbox{E}}\kern-0.1em\LaTeX}
\newcommand{\tXeLaTeX}{\XeLaTeX\index{XeLaTeX@\protect\XeLaTeX}} % Command to print the XeLaTeX logo while simultaneously adding the position to the index

\newcommand{\doccmdnoindex}[2][]{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}} % Command to print a command in texttt with a backslash of tt type without inserting the command into the index

\newcommand{\doccmddef}[2][]{\hlred{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}}\label{cmd:#2}\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}} % Command to define a command in red and add it to the index
{ % If no package is specified, add the command to the index
\index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}% Command name
}
{ % If a package is also specified as a second argument, add the command and package to the index
\index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)}% Command name
\index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}% Package name
}}

\newcommand{\doccmd}[2][]{% Command to define a command and add it to the index
\texttt{\tuftebs#2}%
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}% If no package is specified, add the command to the index
{%
\index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}% Command name
}
{%
\index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)}% Command name
\index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}% Package name
}}

% A bunch of new commands to print commands, arguments, environments, classes, etc within the text using the correct formatting
\newcommand{\docopt}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}
\newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}
\newenvironment{docspec}{\begin{quotation}\ttfamily\parskip0pt\parindent0pt\ignorespaces}{\end{quotation}}
\newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 environment@\texttt{#1} environment}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docenvdef}[1]{\hlred{\texttt{#1}}\label{env:#1}\index{#1 environment@\texttt{#1} environment}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 class option@\texttt{#1} class option}\index{class options!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docclsoptdef}[1]{\hlred{\texttt{#1}}\label{clsopt:#1}\index{#1 class option@\texttt{#1} class option}\index{class options!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docmsg}[2]{\bigskip\begin{fullwidth}\noindent\ttfamily#1\end{fullwidth}\medskip\par\noindent#2}
\newcommand{\docfilehook}[2]{\texttt{#1}\index{file hooks!#2}\index{#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\doccounter}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 counter@\texttt{#1} counter}}

\usepackage{makeidx} % Used to generate the index
\makeindex % Generate the index which is printed at the end of the document

% This block contains a number of shortcuts used throughout the book
\newcommand{\vdqi}{\textit{VDQI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ei}{\textit{EI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ve}{\textit{VE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\be}{\textit{BE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VDQI}{\textit{The Visual Display of Quantitative Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\EI}{\textit{Envisioning Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VE}{\textit{Visual Explanations}\xspace}
\newcommand{\BE}{\textit{Beautiful Evidence}\xspace}
\newcommand{\TL}{Tufte-\LaTeX\xspace}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BOOK META-INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{A Study in Algorithms} % Title of the book

\author[Lee Barney]{Lee Barney} % Author

%\publisher{Lee S. Barney} % Publisher

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle % Print the title page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COPYRIGHT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
\begin{fullwidth}
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
Copyright \copyright\ \the\year\ \thanklessauthor

%\par\smallcaps{Published by \thanklesspublisher}

%\par\smallcaps{tufte-latex.googlecode.com}

\par All rights reserved. \index{license}

\par\textit{First printing, \monthyear}
\end{fullwidth}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\listoffigures % Print a list of figures

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\listoftables % Print a list of tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
\include{intro}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter

\include{a}
\include{b}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\backmatter

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\bibliography{algorithms} % Use the bibliography.bib file for the bibliography
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % Use the plainnat style of referencing

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\printindex % Print the index at the very end of the document

\end{document}```
````

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] that includes the code of `a.tex` and `b.tex`. As long as the object which should be referenced is numbered, your code works fine with just using the normal `\label{...}` and `\ref{...}` mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I am using similar thing in my thesis. Using \hyperref[label]{text you wanna show} in the text is working for me. Don't forget to have package hyperref included.

```
 \label{ab:PCL} % this is inside my abbreviations file
 ---
 \hyperref[ab:PCL]{polycaprolactone} % this is in my text file
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).